# Jquery - never mind dropping the leading zero, how do I keep it?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery driven delete confirmation script that inserts values into hidden form fields and fires off a php delete script.

```
echo "<a class='delete' href='#' onclick='document.delAccForm.delAcc.value = ". $row['AccountNumber']."; document.delAccForm.delMyID.value = ". $row['MyID']."; document.delAccForm.delAccID.value = ". $row['AccountID'].";'>Delete</a>";
```

Form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" name="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="AccountID" value="<?php echo $out['AccountID']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="<?php echo $out['PropertyID']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="formVar" value="">
</form>
```

That all works fine, however certain entries cannot be deleted and on investigation I've found that any account number beginning with 0 is truncated to the first number above 0. This is either a browser action or Jquery treating the number as a value, how can I force it to treat it as a string.

I've tried this format, without success, the html this produced was pretty messed up.

```
<a class='delete' href='#' onclick='document.delAccForm.delAcc.value = '". $row['AccountNumber']."'; document.delAccForm.delMyID.value = '". $row['MyID']."'; document.delAccForm.delAccID.value = '". $row['AccountID']."';'>Delete</a>
```

Comment: You should use double quotes on HTML attribute values

Comment: What is the `$row` variable, where is that being set?

Comment: It's dropping because it's an integer. Try making it a string.

Comment: I suspect `$out['AccountID']` is an integer...

Comment: $row is a php array, the whole thing is being echoed to the page, I've amended the code to suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I think I understand your problem better now. You have HTML links created by PHP and you want to be able to update the values of a hidden HTML form based on values specific to that link. Then you want to submit the form when that link is clicked in order to do server-side processing. The leading 0's are being trimmed when you are setting the values of the form, so the question is how to prevent that.

**HTML + PHP**

Use custom `data` attributes to build up your anchors like so:

`echo '<a class="delete" href="#" data-account-number="'.$row['AccountNumber'].'" data-account-id="'.$row['AccountId'].'" data-my-id="'.$row['MyId'].'">Delete</a>';`

**jQuery/javascript**

Then use this jQuery to attach a click listener to all `delete` anchors. Note that I'm using the `attr()` function, not `data()`. `data()` will try to interpret the datatype and cast it for you, in this case casting your ID's as numbers and trimming the leading 0's. Using `attr` will ensure you are working with strings:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.delete').on('click', function(e) {
        var that = $(this);

        $('#delAcc').val(that.attr('data-account-number')); 
        $('#delMyID').val(that.attr('data-my-id')); 
        $('#delAccID').val(that.attr('data-account-id')); 

        $('form[name="myform"]').submit();
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I see what your trying to do but I'm pulling back a list of accounts in php and echoing variables to the page which are then passed to the form by jquery to help with account selection, is there no way I can do the string conversion inline with the onclick event?

Comment: @Funk247 If the issue is how PHP is echoing the numbers, it won't matter what you do in javascript

Comment: No the numbers are echoed fine by PHP, its when the form recieves them from JQuery that the leading 0 has been stripped, so when I send the form to the delete handler the query fails. Im fairly sure either JQuery or the browser is stripping the leading 0 because the value is an integer when it should be a string.

Comment: @Funk247 Ah, I understand your issue a bit better now. I've updated my answer to include how to pass values from PHP to JS without having to do so much inline scripting and while preserving the leading 0's